# Pass JSON Object from one activity to another Android

Tags: android, json

I am retrieving my JSON response from the Google Places and I want to display it in another Acivity in a ListView. What I am trying to do is to pass the Object from one activity to another, but it doesn't seem to work.

**This is part of my activity which I am trying to pass the JSON from:**

```
public class GetNearbyPlacesList extends AsyncTask<Object, String, String> {

    String googlePlacesData;
    String url;
    List<HashMap<String, String>> nearbyPlacesList = null;
    private Intent context;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor intent;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        try {
            Log.d("GetNearbyPlacesData", "doInBackground entered");
            url = (String) params[0];
            DownloadUrl downloadUrl = new DownloadUrl();
            googlePlacesData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url);
            Log.d("GooglePlaceData", googlePlacesData);
            Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "doInBackground Exit");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", e.toString());
        }
        return googlePlacesData;
    }

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Entered");
                ListParser listParser = new ListParser();
                nearbyPlacesList = listParser.parse(result);
                Log.d("List of restaurants", nearbyPlacesList.toString());
                Log.d("GooglePlacesReadTask", "onPostExecute Exit");
        Intent intent = new Intent(GetNearbyPlacesList.this,ListRestActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("deal", nearbyPlacesList.toString());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**This is the class I want to pass the JSON to:**

```
   public class ListRestActivity extends Activity implements
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener  {


ListView lv;
double latitude;
double longitude;
private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listrest);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }

    //Check if Google Play Services Available or not
    if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
        Log.d("onCreate", "Finishing test case since Google Play Services are not available");
        finish();
    }
    else {
        Log.d("onCreate","Google Play Services available.");
    }

    String Restaurant = "restaurant";

    String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, Restaurant);
    Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[1];
    DataTransfer[0] = url;
    GetNearbyPlacesList getNearbyPlacesList = new GetNearbyPlacesList();
    getNearbyPlacesList.execute(DataTransfer);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second activity, you can access the intent's JSON string with

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("deal");
```

Then you can convert that back into a JSON object if needed.

**Update:**

The reason why you're receiving an error in the Intent constructor in your Async task is because you're not passing in a valid context as a parameter. Your context property is of type Intent when it should be Context so fix that like this:

```
private Context mContext;
```

Add a constructor to your GetNearbyPlacesList like so

```
public GetNearbyPlacesList(Context context) {
    mContext = context
}
```

Pass it a context on instantiation, your first activity most likely.

So then when you construct that intent in your async task class you can do so like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ListRestActivity.class)
```

Comment: I have a warning in onPostExecute that says : Cannot resolve constructor Intent

Comment: Make sure that your variable context you're passing into the Intent constructor is actually a context. I don't see your first activity's declaration, but most likely you need to change 'context' to 'FirstActivity.this' if you're declaring that intent in an inner class.

Comment: Also found a typo in my answer's code snippet. Updated accordingly.

Comment: I added my class declaration and modified context to my activity name but it still gives me the same error. :(

Comment: Updated answer, you need to pass the first activity's context to a custom constructor of your async task so you can use it when constructing the intent. Right now you're passing the async task instance as a context which will produce an error as it isn't a valid context.